# How to capture exit code from a cmdlet in a powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I'm extremely new to powershell scripting and I'm having a hell of a time trying to capture whether something simply failed or succeeded. I have a simple example:

test1.ps1

```
get-psdrive -name ds | out-null

if($? -ne "False")
{ 
   echo "drive doesn't exist"
}
else { echo "Found drive" }
```

This however isn't working for me. I also tried the variable $LastExitCode but that doesn't work either. I'm seriously misunderstanding something here. Can someone please point me in the right direction or show me a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$drive = Get-PSDrive -Name ds 2>Out-Null
```

or

```
$drive = Get-PSDrive -Name ds -EA SilentlyContinue
```

If the cmdlet is successful, `$drive` holds the drive object, otherwise its value is `$null`:

```
if ($drive -eq $null) {
  echo "Drive doesn't exist."
} else {
  echo "Found drive."
}
```

Comment: -EA SilentlyContinue doesn't work most of the time usually you have to do $ErrorAction = "SilentlyContinue" on a separate line  or > Out-Null as mentioned above